# Check variable on if statement

Tags: java, if-statement, netbeans-8

how to check the number of variables at once whether they are "**null**"?

above is my variable :

```
    static String Sinhala;
    static String English;
    static String Arbic;
    static String Spanis;
```

Comment: Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask to avoid downvotes

Comment: use optional (starting from Java 8)

Comment: `int numberOfNulls = (Sinhala == null ? 1 : 0) + (English == null ? 1 : 0) + (Arbic == null ? 1 : 0) + (Spanis == null ? 1 : 0);`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
 if (Sinhala == null || English == null || Arbic == null || Spanis == null)
 {

     //Do something

 }
```

You can combine them all in a single statement

Comment: Probably he wants to know the number of variables which are NULL

Comment: what you thought was correct @cbinder